# Optimal autolayout constraints for user uploaded image

Tags: swift, xcode, autolayout, swift4

What is the best practice for autolayout constraints for user uploaded images? I would like the image to expand to the width of the screen, but the height to be somewhat adjustable depending on the aspect ratio of the image being uploaded. I also want to make sure the height does not take up the entire screen if the original image size is extremely large.

[Image autolayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDcgT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already given the answer! The spec, as you've described it, perfectly expresses the constraints you'll need.

- Pin the image view's sides to the sides of the screen (actually its superview), and pin its top, bottom, or vertical center as desired.
- You'll have to give the image view a height constraint initially, but this will not be the *real* height, so keep a reference to the height constraint so you can replace it later. When you know the aspect ratio of the image, set the image view's aspect ratio by giving it a height constraint whose `multiple` is the desired ratio to the width constraint.
- Add a maximum height constraint as an inequality and all your requirements are met.

Comment: thank you! a couple of followups: 1) How do I set the image view's height constraint multiple ratio? 2) what's the best content mode setting that I should use in my case?

Comment: Well, a constraint has a `multiple` property, so the code is pretty straightforward. There are several ways to construct a constraint; I'm not going to write that code for you. The content mode setting is more interesting! It depends on what you want to see. If you want to see the whole image, you'd better use Aspect Fit.